# Android main activity does not launch on start

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

The main activity does not launch when I open the application; I close it by clicking on the home button. When the app starts, it opens on the same page where I was when I clicked the home button. It somehow remembers the last page I was at, and opens that page instead of the launcher activity. I added onDestroy() to onPause() on all the activities, but that didn't help either.

I am not sure what code to add here, so I'm attaching my AndroidManifest. Thanks! Below are the three activities in the AndroidManifest.

```
  <activity android:name="example.Activity1" android:label="MyApp" 
        android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name="example.Activity2"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="example.Activity3"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: is your package name simply... `example`?

Comment: Try calling `finish()` in `onPause()`

Comment: @Vyger, it isn't. I just replaced the original package name with example, just for the purpose of this post.

Comment: @codeMagic, the answer about adding a flag to the intent worked. But I guess I should have tried finish() too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity is saved on the backstack. Play with the [flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET) passed to the intent when you create your activity. For example, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET will clear all the activities from this to up the backstack.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
startActivity(myintent);
```

When you close, o exit myintent Activity, when you reopen you app it will clear delete myintent Activity from the backstack and all the activities opened from this activity.

Answer (score 4):

When Home button is pressed, **onStop** method is called in your activity. So what you may do is to add `finish();` in **onStop** method to destroy your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you activity name includes you entire package name instead of example.

Or just replace `android:name="example.Activity1"` with `android:name=".Activity1"`